# XSLT escape HTML Entity Codes (&#60; &#62)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to escape some HTML Entity Codes from `<![CDATA[&#60;ul&#62;&#60;li&#62;Linienfl&#252;ge&#60;/li&#62;&#60;/ul&#62;]]>` in XSLT?

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Test.xsl"?>
<re>
  <bl><![CDATA[&#60;ul&#62;&#60;li&#62;Linienfl&#252;ge&#60;/li&#62;&#60;/ul&#62;]]></bl>
</re>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="re">
        <text>  
        <xsl:text >&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select = "bl/."/>
        <xsl:text >]]&gt;</xsl:text>         
        </text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<text>
  <![CDATA[&#60;ul&#62;&#60;li&#62;Linienfl&#252;ge&#60;/li&#62;&#60;/ul&#62;]]>
</text>
```

Expected output:

```
<text>
    <![CDATA[<ul><li>Linienflüge</li></ul>]]>
</text>
```

Comment: Which XSLT 1 processor do you use?

Comment: Hi Martin, i use XslCompiledTransform() in C# it suports only a xslt1.0 syntax.

Comment: Either consider to change to the .NET version of Saxon HE, available on NuGet, for instance, or set up an two extension functions  in C# to parse and serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you could use

```
  <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="re">
    <text>
      <xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment(bl) => parse-xml-fragment() => serialize(map { 'method' : 'xml' })"/>
    </text>
  </xsl:template>
```

XSLT is available on various platforms like Java through Saxon HE 9.8 or later, on .NET through the .NET version of Saxon HE, on JavaScript and Node.js through Saxon-JS 2 and for C/C++ with PHP and Python binding through Saxon-C. Altova in its various products like XMLSpy also has support for XSLT 3.

For XslCompiledTransform you could set up extension functions (https://github.com/martin-honnen/ParseXmlSerializeXslCompiledTransform/blob/master/ParseXmlSerializeXslCompiledTransform/XslCompiledTransformExtensions.cs#L10):

```
   public class MyExtensions
    {
        public static XPathNavigator ParseXmlFragment(string xml)
        {
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment }))
                return new XPathDocument(xr).CreateNavigator();
            }
        }

        public static string Serialize(XPathNavigator node)
        {
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = false }))
                {
                    node.WriteSubtree(xw);
               
                }
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

used in

```
       XslCompiledTransform processor = new XslCompiledTransform();

        processor.Load("XSLTFile1.xslt");

        XsltArgumentList xsltArgumentList = new XsltArgumentList();
        xsltArgumentList.AddExtensionObject("http://example.com/mf", new MyExtensions());

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
            {
                processor.Transform(xr, xsltArgumentList, Console.Out);
            }
        }
```

and called in XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="mf">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="re">
    <text>
      <xsl:value-of select="mf:Serialize(mf:ParseXmlFragment(mf:ParseXmlFragment(bl)))"/>
    </text>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Is there any simple solution for xslt 1.0? Saxon does not run on .NET Core

Comment: I hope Saxonica will be able to release Saxon-CS sooner or later this year. In the meantime, there is XmlPrime or you need to implement extension functions for XslCompiledTransform, as shown in the edit of the answer.

Comment: Why not to use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xml)  insted of ParseXmlFragment(xml) and Serialize(xml)?

Comment: @AlexanderS., mainly because I live in the XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1 world, considered the escaped data as double escaped XML fragment markup, therefore solved the problem with the use of XPath 3.1 `parse-xml-fragment(bl) => parse-xml-fragment() => serialize(map { 'method' : 'xml' })` and then looked to imitate that in the world of XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: ,Ok I understand. I just used {HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xml)} to decode HTML characters in C#. It is simpler and works well. :)

Comment: @AlexanderS., I agree, as long as you only want to work with strings it is simpler, but once you want to transform the strings with XSLT as nodes you need to parse the markup so in the general case where people run into escaped markup in CDATA sections and want to process it further with XSLT the use of parse-xml or parse-xml-fragment and additionally serialize if you want a string back is much more flexible and powerful.